# Associative table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have 4 tables (`Army, Navy, Air Force, Marines`), all have `serial number` as primary key, and `name`. And I have a table `operation` which has `op_num` as primary key and `op_name`. I also have a table `operation member`, which associates the operation table to other 4 tables, how can I write a single SQL statement, return the names of the members (regardless of branch of service) of the covert operation 'Desert Storm' using Microsoft T-SQL syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your association table looks like this

```
Operation_Member (op_num, ser_num)
```

the following query should return the desired result:

```
SELECT Soldier.Name FROM Operation_Member
INNER JOIN Operation
    ON Operation.op_num = Operation_Member.op_num
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ser_num, name FROM Army
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ser_num, name FROM Navy
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ser_num, name FROM Air_Force
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ser_num, name FROM Marines
) Soldier
    ON Soldier.ser_num = Operation_Member.ser_num
WHERE Operation.op_name = 'Desert Storm'
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. sorry Im new to sql. what is Soldier? becasue I dont have table soldier

Comment: Solider is just an alias name. It can be any string, thats all. Instead of Solider, you can put S in everywhere and it will work

Comment: @Sarah, in order to join with all four tables we have to make a derived table here that 'unions' all of them - it's the query inside parentheses. Since it's a kind of a 'virtual' table, we have to give it an alias to refer to it in our outer query. Derived table's alias is added after the closing parenthesis (`) Soldier`).

Comment: oh got it. Thank you.

Comment: This query will fail if the `ser_num` across these four tables can repeat. If they are unique across all tables then this will work. But that's the problem with the data model rather than the query.

Comment: The serial number is not unique across all four services tables

Comment: It has to be. How do you otherwise know person from wich table is referenced in operation members table?