# Associative table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

If I have 4 tables (Army, Navy, Air Force, Marines), all have serial number as primary key, and name. And I have a table operation which has op_num as primary key and op_name. I also have a table operation member, which associates the operation table to other 4 tables, how can I write a single SQL statement, return the names of the members (regardless of branch of service) of the covert operation 'Desert Storm' using Microsoft SQL syntax?

I have this

```
SELECT Soldier.Name FROM Operation_Member
INNER JOIN Operation
    ON Operation.op_num = Operation_Member.op_num
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ser_num, name FROM Army
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ser_num, name FROM Navy
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ser_num, name FROM Air_Force
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ser_num, name FROM Marines
) Soldier
    ON Soldier.ser_num = Operation_Member.ser_num
WHERE Operation.op_name = 'Desert Storm'
```

But this wont work if the serial number is not unique across all four services tables.
Is there a way to do it to make sure it works with that condition?

Comment: Follow up of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36613802/associative-table-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the serial number is not unique across all four services tables, then there is no way to know which of the duplicates is referred to in Operation_Member, unless you also store the service branch in Operation_Member too.

If you do, then the query becomes this

```
SELECT Soldier.Name 
FROM 
    Operation
    INNER JOIN 
    Operation_Member ON Operation.op_num = Operation_Member.op_num
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT branchid, ser_num, name FROM Army
        UNION ALL
        SELECT branchid, ser_num, name FROM Navy
        UNION ALL
        SELECT branchid, ser_num, name FROM Air_Force
        UNION ALL
        SELECT branchid, ser_num, name FROM Marines
    ) Soldier
        ON Soldier.ser_num = Operation_Member.ser_num
                 AND Soldier.branchid= Operation_Member.branchid
WHERE Operation.op_name = 'Desert Storm'
```

If you don't, there is no way to remove ambiguity